# Is there any way to remove html element by context?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have this following html code

```html
<ui id="fruits">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
    <li>melon</li>
</ui>
```

now the question is: is there any function in jquery like `$("#furits").removeElement("apple")` to remove a element by context?

I tried the [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function in jquery, however it can only remove element by class,id,name etc, but i want remove a element by context?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use a combination of `:contains` and `remove()`, like this:

```js
$('#fruits li:contains("apple")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ui id="fruits">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
    <li>melon</li>
</ui>
```

It's worth noting that `:contains` is both a greedy match and also case-sensitive. This means `Apple` would not match `apple`, but would match `Crab Apple`, for example.

If you require an *exact* match you could use `filter()` instead:

```js
let search = 'apple';
$('#fruits li').filter((i, el) => el.textContent.trim() === search).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ui id="fruits">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
    <li>melon</li>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. You would need to iterate through the children and compare values.

```
$('#fruits li').each(function(){
   if ($(this).text() === 'apple') {
       $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: My bad. ```.text()``` should work. I changed the answer

Comment: nevermind, thx your answer but there have some better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help

```js
$("#fruits li").remove( ":contains('apple')" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ui id="fruits">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
    <li>melon</li>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function from where you can remove child elements as:

```js
const fruitsEl = document.querySelector("#fruits");

function removeChild(elementToRemoved) {
  if (elementToRemoved && fruitsEl) {
    const children = [...fruitsEl.children];
    for (let child of children) {
      const text = child.textContent.trim();
      if (text === elementToRemoved) fruitsEl.removeChild(child);
    }
  }
}

removeChild("apple");
```

```html
<ui id="fruits">
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>lemon</li>
  <li>melon</li>
</ui>
```